# jQuery arrow scrolling

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

Currently my one page website has 4 different sections that have 100% height(main-containers.) I can scroll to each section with the arrow keys. My navigation links also stay highlighted when I click them. The problem is by scrolling down the page my jQuery doesn't remember the position. Also if I were to click on a navigation link and scroll to the next section (with mouse) the link stays highlighted and doesn't change to the current section. Help would be much appreciated.

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/phUxg/2/

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
var lengthDiv = $('.desktop').find('li').length;
var current = 0;
$('a').bind('click',function(event){

var $anchor = $(this);
current = $anchor.parent().index();

$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href#')).offset().top
}, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
/*
if you don't want to use the easing effects:
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
}, 1000);
*/
event.preventDefault();
});
$(document).keydown(function(e){if($(':focus').length <= 0)e.preventDefault()})
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if(key == 38 && current > 0){
        $('.desktop').children('li').eq(current - 1).children('a').trigger('click')
    }else if(key == 40 && current < lengthDiv){
        $('.desktop').children('li').eq(current + 1).children('a').trigger('click')
    }
})
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".desktop a").click(function() {
$(".desktop a").removeClass("selected");
$(this).addClass("selected"); 
});
});
});
```

Comment: what's this `$anchor.attr('href#')` in your code?? did you meant `$anchor.attr('href')` ??

Comment: I have multiple navigations in my code that appear according to the screen size. I used that to specify the navigation. It can be turned just into href.

Comment: ideally I am trying to turn my navigation like this: http://pagescroller.com